# how can i avoid function with 2 optional parameters in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax, overloading, optional-parameters

How can I avoid function with 2 optional parameters in vb.net?
What to if parameter names are used to call function?
For Example:

```
Public Function ABC(ByRef a As Integer, Optional b As Integer = 0, Optional c As Integer = 0) As Integer
    'do something  
End Function
```

In this case how overloading is done?
Scenarios are with a, with a and b, with a and c and with a,b,c.

Comment: actually what language you are using? it seem some hybrid of c# and vb

Comment: Please fix your definition. Either VB.net or C#. Also optional parameters require a default value.

Comment: Okay now what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Overloading here will not work because the parameters are all of the same type, meaning the signature of "a and b" and "a and c" would be the same.

For more info see [wikipedia article on overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) which states in the rules:

> The overloaded function must differ either by the arity or data types.

What you have will work completely fine - you can either omit the arguments completely or specify individually using the `:=` notation:

- a `ABC(1)` or `ABC(a:=1)`
- a and b `ABC(1, 2)` or `ABC(a:=1, b:=2)`
- a and c `ABC(1, , 3)` or `ABC(1, c:=3)`
- a, b, c `ABC(1, 2, 3)` or `ABC(a:=1, b:=2, c:=3)`

Comment: Do I have to add 4 different functions? Can you explain the usage of ABC(1,c:=3).

Comment: No you just call the same function in a different way.

Comment: Can you help me with a sample please? I'am Supposed to remove the usage of optional keyword.

Comment: Sample given in my answer

Comment: Actually i'am not supposed to use optional keyword at all.

Comment: This answer says it all. If you want to set the parameters individual and discard the ones you don't want to set explicitly you need the `Optional`-keyword. You can't solve it with overloading because your two optional parameters have the same type. If you don't want many functions and don't want the `Optional` keyword, just drop it and call the function with `0` filled.

Comment: Ya correct but what if user calls function with names and call a  and c?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway: I assume, the default value for your optional integers is zero.

You better should not use the optional parameters, but overloads.

The Problem is only with a/b against a/c, because the number and type of the arguments are the same.
For one of those cases the overload must have a different name (here: `ABCopt`)

Anyway, each overload is just a one-liner with a call to the main function

```
Public Function ABC(a as int)
    Return ABC(a, 0, 0)
End Function

Public Function ABC(a as int, b as int)
    Return ABC(a, b, 0)
End Function

Public Function ABCopt(a as int, c as int)
    Return ABC(a, 0, c)
End Function

Public Function ABC(a as int, b as int, c as int)
    ' Do something with a, b, c
    ' ...
End Function
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to reduce the number of function or use recursion or something?

Comment: @nithinnayak - if your assignment is to get rid of optional then this is it.